# Uncheck a checked checkbox with jquery in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have several checkboxes inside an UpdatePanel of asp.net

Let's say, I have 3 checkboxes in that panel. Each time, one checkbox is checked, the previous checked checkbox will be unchecked.

I have tried like this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxExport1" CssClass="checkboxSingle" />                                     

<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxExport1" CssClass="checkboxSingle" />                                     

<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxExport1" CssClass="checkboxSingle" />
```

In js:

```
 $('.checkboxSingle').live('click', function (e) {

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(".checkboxSingle").attr('checked', false);
            $(this).attr('checked', 'checked')
        }
    });
```

The click is function but the rest does not.

Comment: Your code works fine for me here http://jsfiddle.net/wYH44/2/.

Comment: Why don't you just use `<asp:RadioButton>`? Also, in ASP, shouldn't the value of the `checked`-attribute be `true` instead of `checked`?

Comment: is it a problem if I put them inside an UpdatePanel? @ipr101

Comment: @devn The update panel could be making a difference - see http://forums.asp.net/t/1189519.aspx/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is that on postback the page reloads and the JavaScript doesn't re-run. I'm posting from my phone so I don't have the code on me. But google "updatepanel JavaScript postback". You need to use an asp page event.

I'll edit this later if you tell me you can't find it.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, (asp:CheckBox) is rendered as a (span) with label and input field with type="check".
So when you are trying to say `$(".chkboxClass").removeAttr('checked');` you are actually calling the (span) tag and that is the reason it is not working. To make it works just add:

```
$(".chkboxClass :input").removeAttr('checked');
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

this is similar to DigitalFox response, but this is how I got it to work:

```
$(".checkboxSingle input").is(":checked");
```